# How can I pass getchar(); without pressing Enter, to make it auto?

Tags: c++, helper, getchar

How can I pass the `getchar` to make it proceed without pressing Enter all the time?

```
      printf("\n\n\t [ HTTPd version press intro...... ]\n");
  getchar();
  system("clear");
  printf("HTTPd version for %s\n\n", argv[1]);

  send(sock, "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n\n",17,0);

  recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer),0);
  printf("%s",buffer);
  close(sock);
  printf("\n\t [ Search bugs CGI press intro...... ]\n");
  getchar();
  system("clear");
  printf("Searching.....\n\n");

    while(h3z++ < 218)
```

Comment: Why are you using `printf` and `getchar` if you are coding in c++ ?

Comment: What?  If you don't want `getchar()` to pause the program just get rid of it.

Comment: What is "press intro"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using linux, so, you can use this at starting of program after that all inputs will be read without pressing return key (It will stop echoing pressed character, I think this will look good)

```
system ("/bin/stty raw");
system ("/bin/stty -echo");
```

remember to make everything normal before end of program

```
system ("/bin/stty cooked");
system ("/bin/stty echo");
```

Or, You can Create a separate function including `getchar()` and these codes according to your requirement.

For windows user, one can simply use `getch()` in `<conio.h>`